# Cannot find annotation method 'anyOf()' in type 'RequiresPermission':

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to port an Android app in Android Studio to Visual Studio 2015 / Xamarin. I try to run the project and I get:

```
    Android application is debugging.
    The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).

Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.
```

I added `[Activity(MainLauncher = true)]` to the main class and checked `Build->Configuration` which appears to be correct, but these have no effect.

I get this warning:

```
Cannot find annotation method 'anyOf()' in type 'RequiresPermission': 
class file for android.support.annotation.RequiresPermission not found  
MyApplication.Native.Droid  C:\Users\allelopath\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Maps\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar(com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.class)
```

I also get this warning:

```
Warning     
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. 
In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; 
otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding> 
Acquaint.Native.Droid
```

I double click as it suggests and it asks:

```
Do you want to fix these conflicts by adding binding redirrect records in the application configuration file?
```

I click Yes. This ultimately has no effect, after rebuilding and trying to run, the warning reappears.

I unstalled the app on the device, which had been there from running it on Android Studio, but this had no effect either.

What can you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem I would right click on your solution, go to Configuration Properties and ensure that all of the correct projects are being built and that your android project's Deploy box is checked.  This is just a bad Xamarin tendency.

I have the second warning myself and it is simply because the Android Support Library requires you to compile against sdk version 23.  The Google maps package must use these new annotations.  I haven't encountered any problems because of this error, with a minSdkVersion of 15, so I just live with it.

I also have the same dependent assembly warning and what I think is happening is I have one project which is using a newer reference to .net primitives than whatever .net http is using.  Just a guess but I am also not worried about making this happy.